# Performance tuning in Redshift for multiple update statement

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with huge volume in redshift , I need to run a multiple update statement on different column joining with some static table it takes more then hour to complete all the update execution, is there any way we can improve the performance for this query.

Ex:

```
update customer
set x=y.x
from y

update customer
set z=a.z
from a

update customer
set b=d.b
from b
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp table that contains all changes and the make them all in a single `UPDATE` statement.